# Fatal error catched by register_shutdown_function and update json_encode

Tags: php, json, fatal-error

I can catch a fatal error with `register_shutdown_function('shutdown')`

```
function shutdown(){
    $error = error_get_last();
    $result['message'] = $error['message'];
}
```

and I have an `echo json_encode($result);`

Unfortunately this `echo json_encode` shows nothing because json is not updated with the message of the fatal error.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `$result` is undefined in the scope of your function. Is it a global variable?

Comment: not it is not a global. it is one file with the function register_shutdown_function('shutdown') and function shutdown() and this file included in the index.php file in which at the end has echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why move one array to another array and then echo the second array.

Why not just do this

```
function shutdown(){
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo json_encode($error);
}
```

Or even this

```
function shutdown(){
    echo json_encode(error_get_last());
}
```

Apart form the use of an unnecessary array, this will give you all the information available from `get_last_error()`

Of course it could be that the `error_get_last()` information is just not available at this late stage in the shutdown process. If this is the case then you can pass extra parameters to the shutdown function and this may be what you need to do.

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown', get_last_error());
```

and

```
function shutdown($last_error){
    echo json_encode($last_error);
}
```

**EDITED**:

First I have added `error_reporting(~E_ERROR); // don't report fatal errors`

The first one worked for me I mean

```
error_reporting(~E_ERROR); // don't report fatal 

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function shutdown(){
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] === 1){ 
         echo json_encode($error);
}
```

For my needs I wrote:

```
function shutdown(){
    $error = error_get_last();

    if ($error['type'] === 1){ // 1 means fatal error
         $res['message'] = $error['message'];

         $res['success'] = true;

         header('Content-Type: application/json');

         echo json_encode($res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry then I am plumb out of ideas, but I look forward to seeing the correct answer.

Comment: So friend yeah it worked I should add some more code (headers)... thanks

Comment: So which bit worked? Just so others finding this get a good answer. Feel free to edit the answer with anything extra you had to do